# Android: on Pause(), onStop() or onDestroy() not called on screen orientation change

Tags: android, screen-orientation, ondestroy

on Pause(), onStop() or onDestroy() is not called on changing screen orientation from Portrait to Landscape. Am I missing something?

Here is the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Are you using `android:configChanges` in your manifest? If so, remove that.

Comment: @kcoppock is on destroy called on config changes? :)

Comment: Nope, configChanges explicitly disables the activity being destroyed for whatever configuration change you explicitly handle (e.g. rotation)

Comment: no I am not using android:configChanges in manifest.

Comment: Anyway check `onConfigurationChanged()` is also not called

Comment: No onConfigurationChanged() is not called.

Comment: Post code and your manifest and you will get much better feedback/answers.

Comment: I have added the manifest

Comment: onOrientationChanged()? is that being called in the activity at all?

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your activity

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

Manifest should look like:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
 android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```